# Do the rounded edges of the Galaxy 7 Edge cause distortion with Samsung Gear VR?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-7-edge, samsung-gear-vr

I plan on buying a Galaxy 7 and a Gear VR. I know the Gear VR is compatible with both Edge and non-edge models. But, do the rounded edges of the Edge model create clipping or visual distortion when viewed through the Samsung Gear VR?

Comment: Update : I found this article that claims the Edge is in fact better then non-edge with Gear VR: https://www.androidpit.com/samsung-galaxy-s7-edge-review.

Answer (score 1):

I have the S7Edge and purchased the S-VR latest (black) model and have had nor seen any issues with the edge of the screen at all.  Graphics are smooth and I didn't even think about this until stumbled across your question.  A nice combo but you can't go too long (30min) before the S7 heats up and you need to take a break.